# Is $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}\right)$ finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a practice exam, there is a question asking if $$
\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}\right)
$$ is finite, countably infinite, or uncountable. The solution to the practice exam says this is finite. Is this true?

I think it should be uncountable. $\left(-\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{1}\right)$ is uncountable, and is the first interval. The union of this interval with any other interval will also be uncountable.

The only way I can see this being true is if I have misunderstood the notation, and it is saying the number of intervals is finite. However, I don't believe this is the case.

Comment: Your analysis makes sense to me. Perhaps it is a misprint and was meant to be an intersection instead of a union.

Comment: @David That makes sense. And just as a sanity check, if it were an intersection rather than a union, the final answer would be {0}, which is finite?

Comment: I agree with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}\right)=(-1,1)\cup\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)\cup\dots=(-1,1)$$
If your intervals are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then this interval is uncountable.

Comment: Is assuming the intervals are subsets of R a reasonable assumption when it is not specified?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on the context of the question. If you are instead working with $\mathbb{Q}$, then the interval would be countably infinite.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is asking you if the union is a finite, countable, or uncountable union. In which case since one index $i=1$ is enough to describe the resulting interval, this is a finite union. But you are correct these intervals are uncountable (assuming we are working in $\mathbb{R}$), So you may also want to check the space you are working with.